# Can there be a theory "on" something?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, difference

I want to express that the theory "bow-wow" is one of the theories explaining the origin of language. I know the preposition "of" is mostly used here but is this sentence correct as well?

*Hypotheses "bow-wow" is one of the historical theories on the origin of language.*

Comment: _Theory on_ sounds very conversational and informal. _"I have a theory on the making of the perfect margarita..."_ In a formal context, use _of_ (_Theory of Bow-wow_) or a capitalized "proper name" as an adjunct to "theory", e.g. _"String Theory"._

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use "on" with "theory".

Given the subject matter *bow-wow* as you propose,

- a theory *of* bow-wow is something that explains *bow-wow* comprehensively (compare: theory of relativity) or, alternatively, it is a theory that is set within *bow-wow* (compare: non-contradiction is a law *of* logic); but
- a theory *on* bow-wow is something that discusses aspects of *bow-wow*, but doesn't claim to be comprehensive (compare: the detective has a theory on the police case).

The use of "on" serves to not claim more than is warranted and can be found in mathematical works, among other places. Here's an example:

> Pi, Monads, and the Quasi-Circle Theory: A theory on the circle more
>   [- Lionel Fabius](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=sUj6jn300ncC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22a%20theory%20on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBsYDOw_nUAhVHE7wKHe4jBysQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=%22a%20theory%20on%22&f=false)

In your example, assuming you meant to say *hypothesis* (singular), the word *theory* is used in the sense of a 'guess' as opposed to a proven theorems. Used in this sense, *theory on X* is more appropriate than *theory of X*, unless *X* is the name of that theory.

> **theory** *noun*
>   1.2 An idea used to account for a situation or justify a course of action.
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/theory)

Answer (score 0):

> Hypotheses "bow-wow" is one of the historical theories on the origin of language.

probably passes muster today. The use of **theory on the** would seem on the rise today while **theory of the**.["theory of the" Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=theory%20of%20the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctheory%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0) is not. ["theory on the" Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=theory%20on%20the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctheory%20on%20the%3B%2Cc0)

There seems to have been a rise in the use of **theory on what** and, especially, **theory on why** recently ["theory of what" Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=theory%20on%20what&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctheory%20on%20what%3B%2Cc0). ["theory on why" Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=theory%20on%20why&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctheory%20on%20why%3B%2Cc0).

I would prefer **theory of**, but it does not seem reasonable to call **theory on** unacceptable.

Comment: Ngrams can be very misleading, and in this case they are very misleading. (1) Look what happens when [all four Ngrams are plotted together](http://bit.ly/2sAyvQP)—the opposite conclusion, it would seem. (2) Word counts shed light on correctness only when combined with some insight into meaning. Look what happens when you plot ["theory on" against "theory at" and "theory to"](http://bit.ly/2sYmS5H). Ngrams might seem like a "scientific" way to answer this kind of question, but they're not.

Comment: @BenKovitz Don't kill the messanger, Ngram is a precise tool if you watch the actual percentages.

Comment: @Probably Precision ≠ accuracy. Percentages ≠ correctness ≠ meaning. Seriously, watch out for this fallacy. The apparent "scientificness" and "objectivity" of "precise" tools misleads people in many domains. The problem is particularly bad when trying to use Ngrams as a substitute for knowledge learned from real experience with usage and communication.

Comment: @ Ben Kovitz... i agree about what may be misleading here..... "Theory on" has advanced some, while "theory of" has declined. That surprised me. But I did nor endorse "theory on", I endorsed "theory of".. Given the rise of "theory on why" and "theory on what"., I could not declared  theory on the"  unacceptable

Comment: @BenKovitz I know the difference but I see no connection with this situation. If you know what you need and what the data's showing, a precise tool can give you valuable information.

Comment: @J.Taylor I think those are very slight deviations for Ngram to [infer anything](https://www.wired.com/2015/10/pitfalls-of-studying-language-with-google-ngram/) from them.

Comment: @Probably..... if you see nothing in the Ngram, perhaps you should ignore any inference. i wrote I would use  "theory of".